# Different ways of solving simultaneous equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Given \begin{align} x-2y &= 4\tag1\label1 \\ 2x+3y &= 1 \tag2\label2 \end{align}

One method I know of solving for x and y: elimination by making coefficients the same

$2 \times \eqref{1}:$

$$2x-4y=8\tag3\label3$$

$\eqref{3}-\eqref{2}:$

$$(2x-2x)-4y-3y=8-1\tag4\label4$$

$$-7y=7$$

$$y=-1$$
Sub $y=-1$ into $\eqref{1}$ then 
$$x=2$$

> What are other ways of solving these simultaneous equations? And can you demonstrate your way also.

Comment: Any other method is essentially the same. You could just guess x until you get it right though....not a recommended method!

Comment: There is a linear algebra way but it is sort of an overkill for such a simple pair of equations. (and it uses the same idea anyway) Your method is kind of the most efficient non-calculator way already.

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to subtract an equation from another to eliminate a variable (for example solving a quadratic and linear system of equations). In that case one might use substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrices can be used to re-write $n$ simultaneous equations with $n$ unknowns.

Let's take your example:
$$x-2y=4$$
$$2x+3y=1$$
These can be re-written in matrix form as follows:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -2 \\
    2 & 3 \\
    \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
4\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Next, we can pre-multiply both sides by the inverse of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -2 \\
    2 & 3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ 
leaving 
$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}$ on its own on the LHS. This is utilizing the rule that any matrix $A$ when multiplied by its inverse $A^{-1}$ results in a matrix known as the **identity** matrix, which in the case of 2x2 matrices is $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$  . The identity matrix has similar properties to that of the number $1$, where if you multiply something by it, the result is the same as the value you are multiplying.

We are now left with the follow result:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -2 \\
    2 & 3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
\begin{bmatrix}
4\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This can then be evaluated to give the answer:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
-1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

[How to find the inverse of a 2x2 matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Wto.gif)